# Binding event handlers in PyQT

Tags: python, events, pyqt5

Using PyQt5, there are certain event handlers which I can bind to my object, and others that only work if I implement them as methods. *changeEvent* and *event* are examples of the later type.

You can see in my example below that I can add a *keyPressEvent* handler to my widget programmatically, but I can not do the same thing for *changeEvent*.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

import types

def keyPressEvent(self, key: QtGui.QKeyEvent) -> None:
    #works
    print(key.isAutoRepeat())

def changeEvent(self, a0: QtCore.QEvent) -> None:
    #doesn't work
    print("bound change event", a0.type())


bindable = [keyPressEvent, changeEvent]

def bind_key_functions(target):
    for bound in bindable:
        setattr(target, bound.__name__, types.MethodType(bound, target))

class my_widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("w1")
        bind_key_functions(self)


class my_widget2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("w2")

    def changeEvent(self, a0: QtCore.QEvent) -> None:
        #this does work
        print("derived change event", a0.type())

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
mw1 = my_widget()
mw1.show()
mw2 = my_widget2()
mw2.show()
app.exec_()
```

What makes the *changeEvent* different? how can I force it to behave as I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using setattr to override methods is a bad choice as it is not very elegant and if you want to listen to the events of another QWidget then it is better to use an event filter.

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class Binder(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, qobject):
        super().__init__(qobject)
        self._qobject = qobject
        self.qobject.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def qobject(self):
        return self._qobject

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.qobject is obj:
            print(event.type(), event)

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class My_Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("w1")
        Binder(self)


class My_Widget2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("w2")


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
mw1 = My_Widget()
mw1.show()
mw2 = My_Widget2()
mw2.show()
app.exec_()
```

On the other hand, it is not documented which methods can be assigned or not, so if you want to find the reason you must analyze the source code of sip and pyqt5. What little is pointed out is that PyQt5 creates a cache of the methods (it is not known when or what methods are stored in the cache).

Comment: I thought that eventFilter is somewhat discouraged as it can cause a performance hit on every event. I am not trying to listen to the events of an other widget, just trying to add the same functionality to a number of different kinds of widgets without using multiple inheritance.

Comment: Also, my reason for using this binder approach is because I wanted to use it on both classes that I dindn't want to limit the shared dependencies of inheritance